# Brute force 2048, getting stupid with setInterval

Tags: javascript

This game, [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/), is too addicting. I need to automate playing it. Something is wrong with my `setInterval`, as it is only firing my function once. Thanks for the help.

```
var game = $('.game-container');

function fire(el)
{   
    var moves = [37,38,39,40]
    var key = moves[Math.floor(Math.random()*moves.length)];
    if(document.createEventObject)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEventObject();
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);  
    }else if(document.createEvent)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
        eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
        eventObj.which = key;
        el.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
}

window.setInterval(fire(game),100);
```

It seems to run the function once and then I get: `Application Cache NoUpdate event` in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) takes a string or a function variable:

```
// string syntax (NOT RECOMMENDED)
// passes "fire(game)" to eval() every 100ms.
// executes in the global scope, which is a potential scope change. thus,
// has the potential to "lose" its reference to your `fire` and `game` variables.
setInterval("fire(game)", 100);

// function-passing syntax (PREFERRED)
// executes the [anonymous] function every 100ms.
// holds onto the in-scope `fire` and `game` objects.
setInterval(function() { fire(game); }, 100);
```

Doing this:

```
setInterval(fire(game), 100);
```

... will call `fire(game)` and pass the return value to `setInterval`. This would be meaningful if `fire(game)` returned a `function`. (Or a `string` that could be `eval()`'d, though I'd advise against it!)

Comment: FYI Passing a string to `setInterval` uses `eval` and is therefore not recommended ;-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Updated to note preferred syntax.

Comment: So... `fire(game)` is not really a function. It is what it returns. Which is not a function. Kind of confusing.

Comment: @broinjc: `fire` is a function.  `fire(game)` calls the `fire` function, so its return value is used.

Answer (score 0):

You call fire in the last line instead of actually setting an interval.

`fire(game)` doesn't return anything, so it doesn't pass `setInterval` any callback.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
fire(game)
```

In `setInterval` will actually call the function, and the `setInterval` will never execute any function

Try

```
setInterval(function(){fire(game)},100);
```